# What’s the proper punctation for: “Work”, you ask?

Tags: punctuation

I’m writing a tweet that starts with:

> Put on a tie today. “Work,” you ask?

But I’m not sure where the punctuation should be. Is the above correct? Or, is it something like:

> Put on a tie today. “Work?” you ask.

Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Put on a tie today* is an order.  *Put a tie on today* is what you did.

I believe that

> "Work?" you ask.

Is correct.

Comment: How is it that *Put on a tie today* can only be an order? I read it as a perfectly natural statement of what OP did.

Comment: @JAM perhaps *order* is a bit strong, and perhaps it's just my interpretation.  For me, the subtle distinction comes with the dropped/implied subject.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith, Why not just say, "I put on a tie today." in your tweet? It's only two more characters and a lot clearer.

Comment: I ended up [using all 140 available characters](https://twitter.com/TheIdOfAlan/status/230880002760134657). I changed it up a little. There was probably another edit I could have made but I think it'll get the point across.

Comment: *Put on a tie today* is strictly speaking imperative, but it's a colloquial drop of the pronoun "I". "[I am] Going out for a bit!".

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the type of question as

> "Why?" you may ask.

So this should be:

> "Work?" you ask.

You see, work functions as the question as a quotation implying a certain tone whereas  you ask is separately a part of the written document.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE. Thanks for sharing. I've adjusted the style of your answer and made it so it would be clearer for others to comprehend the logic behind your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Put on a tie today. "Work?" - you ask - no, just in that kind of mood!

(Or whatever the rest of your sentence is)